# flask-wtforms show a popup after clicking on submit button

Tags: python, flask

I am using flask wtform and i want to show a confirmation popup after pressing the submit button so user can see that their submission is successful.

forms.py:

```
    post = FloatField('', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Quote')
```

.html:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('product', id=product.id) }}" method="post">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <h4>
        {{ form.post(class='input-text qty', maxlength='9', placeholder='Price') }}
        {{ form.submit(class='button primary-btn', id='orderform') }}
    </h4>
</form>
.
.
.
.
.
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("orderform").submit(function(){
             alert("Submitted");
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i press the submit button the value is added to the database but i don't get any confirmation popup.

Answer (score 1):

Flask has a built-in functionality called [Flash](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/), it should be able to provide a feedback for your application, you just have to import this on your routes.py:

`from flask import flash`

Then, also on your routes.py file, when you want to call the message, just call the flash method:

`flash("Your submission is successful")`

And finally, at your .html, allow the page to receive the flashing messages:

```
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
            {% if messages %}
                {% for msgs in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                        {{msgs}}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
```